# Can I select element in Selenuim with action?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I need to select element in C# with Selenium.

The element doesn't have an ID, or name.

I tried with `XPath`, but it does not work.

The element have an "action" `(action="/Cars")`.

I tried this:

```
  IWebElement car = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("my xpath")); 
  car.Click();
```

I need to be more specific, because on some pages the XPath is the same with different elements.

Is it possible to select it with an action?

Comment: Can you not use `SelectElement`? Show us your attempt so far?

Comment: IWebElement car = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("my xpath"));
            car.Click(); 
I need to be more specific, because on some pages the XPath is the same with different elements.

Comment: can you edit your question and post your answer there?

Comment: it is like a form element since it has 'action'  attribute, so you can select by attribute value like : By.cssSelector("form[action='/Cars']")

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can select by any attribute which has value

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@action='Cars']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Any tag with an attribute can be selected via an XPath.

Consider the following example
`<a href=/something attribute1=value1 attribute2=value2 ... />`

To access an element with the attribute, you should follow the below

`.//a[@attribute1='value1']` or `.//a[contains(@attribute1,'value1')]`

here,

**.** specifies the xpath to start from current value in DOM

**@** is used identify the attribute

and,

**contains** can be helpful when text has some padding or you only want to match partial text